# XAML: Rounded corners for all Images inside a FlowDocument!

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, visual-studio, xaml

I want to give all images inside a FlowDocument rounded corners.
Whats the easiest way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put each image in a Border and set the border's corner radius